# Angular routing not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, routes

I have problem with angular routing.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.2.16" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular-route.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="loginController.js"></script>
  <script src="loginService.js"></script>
  <script src="AppController.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="betsApp" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

AppController.js

```
var betsApp = angular.module('betsApp', ['ngRoute', 'loginApp', 'loginService']);

betsApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
{
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: '/error.html'})
        .when('/login', {templateUrl: '/pages/loginView.html'});
});

betsApp.controller('appCtrl', function($scope)
{

});
```

loginView.html:

```
<div ng-app="loginApp" ng-controller="loginCtrl">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <hr>
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" ng-model="credentials.email" value="{{credentials.email}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" ng-model="credentials.password" value="{{credentials.password}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="button" value="Login" ng-click="doLogin()">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The problem is that I see only a white page without any inserted view. **[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/s0Apw17pgn2n8pa3tXct?p=preview) is a link to plunker**.

Comment: Tried to define the controller in the `$routeProvider`?

Comment: no, the controller defined in the module

Comment: I mean to explicitly define it:

`.when('/login', {templateUrl: '/pages/loginView.html',
 controller: 'loginCtrl' });`

Comment: no, i don't think it is the issue because the error page (which has only some text in it) is also doesn't shows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link to the plnkr does not match the code you have provided above (route definitions)

That being said I was able to get it routing by turning off html5Mode

*Note: even angular's routing example does not work w/ html5Mode on... http://plnkr.co/edit/7YNtWncWYtxceELnzkAT?p=preview*

Also, in loginView you are trying to define `ng-app="loginApp"` that will not be allowed, while you can have nested ng-app's (unless you manually bootstrap them [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp))

Comment: But I do need to turn it on, I don't want to use the `#`.

Comment: And you can turn it on within your app, but I do not believe plnkr can handle it.

Comment: I don't believe that plnkr can handle html5 mode routing, but when you run your app outside the context of plnkr then you can use html5 routing.